Haunted movie in which a woman takes a shower and blood comes from the shower and falls over her body
I saw a movie where a actress bathes nude in a shower and suddenly blood comes from the shower and falls over her body. Her nude body is shown. She also has a child aged 10 or 11 and an actor, maybe her husband or boyfriend, is shown staying in a haunted house.
The movie was from the 70s or 80s.

https://www.reddit.com/r/HorrorMovies/comments/14mec0v/shower_blood_movie/

Hmmm, that's a tough one. I just saw one recently from that era involving blood from a shower, but I don't remember a kid in it. What I do remember is that the entity in the house caused the shower head to pull away from the pipe and impale the woman in the throat. But bloody baths were a common trope back then as well. Do you remember the language of the film and where you might have seen it?

Full nudity makes it likely to be an Italian splatter movie.

Could be This House Possessed (1981) - bloody shower and collapsing to shower floor (but nudity implied)- see the clip below (no nudity):



This house posssessed

Does the woman have a child?

The house that dripped blood?
